# I'm using Dev C++ and subtraction is not working

Tags: dev-c++

I'm using Subtraction option in Dev C++ .I enter values but it always gives me an empty answer
[Look Code Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdAwZ.png)

[Look Error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnB8X.png)

Comment: Put your code inside the question itself

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to print the final answer LMAO. LMAO contains your subtracted value but you have to print it.

```
cout<<"Answer \n"<<LMAO<<endl;
```

This will work.